# I Can't access the information from the wrapper to LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

Hey I build this LWC where I want to create a Accordion Section to show up a list of images that are storage in different Sobjects. The Ideia is to have an accordion with the structure of SObjects -> Folders -> Photo

This is my controller

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<TVA_CFB__Cloud_Files__c> getPhotoData() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name, TVA_CFB__Folder__c, TVA_CFB__View_File__c, Order__c From TVA_CFB__Cloud_Files__c order by CreatedDate Desc limit 10];
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<FileCloud> getPhoto(String caseId){

        Case cs = [Select Id,Opportunity__c, Project_QA_Review__c, Service_Appointment__c, Order__c  From Case where Id =: caseId];

        Id opportunityId = cs.Opportunity__c;
        Id projectQAId = cs.Project_QA_Review__c;
        Id serviceAppId = cs.Service_Appointment__c;
        Id orderId = cs.Order__c;

        TVA_CFB__CloudFiles_Settings__c credentials = TVA_CFB__CloudFiles_Settings__c.getInstance (UserInfo.getUserID ());
        Map <String, TVA_CFB__Cloud_Files_Region_Endpoints__c> regionEndPoints = TVA_CFB__Cloud_Files_Region_Endpoints__c.getAll ();
        Map <ID, String> fileURlsMap = new Map <ID, String> ();
        Map <String, SObject> cloudFile = new Map <String, SObject> ();
        List<FileCloud> fileCloudList = new List<FileCloud>();
        try {
            
            
            for(TVA_CFB__Cloud_Files__c obj : [SELECT ID,
            Name, TVA_CFB__Bucket_Name__c, TVA_CFB__Region__c, TVA_CFB__Folder__c,
            TVA_CFB__File_type__c, TVA_CFB__External_File_name__c, Opportunity__c, GO_Case__c, QA_Review__c, Service_Appointment__c, Order__c
            FROM TVA_CFB__Cloud_Files__c WHERE TVA_CFB__Folder__c != null AND TVA_CFB__Folder__c IN ('Signed Offer', 'SEPA', 'Abtretungsanzeige',
            'Confirmation of registration with Marktstammdatenregistrierung (Auszug MaStR)', 'Wiring Plan (Schaltplan)',
            'Application for registration with grid operator (Inbetriebsetzungsantrag Zählerwechsel)', 'Commissioning protocol (Inbetriebsetzungsprotokoll E8)',
            'Inbetriebssetzungsprotokoll Speicher E3', 'MaStR Batteriespeicher', 'Service Reports', 'Fotos Fertige PV-Anlage & Module',
            'Invoices', 'Fotos bereits vorhandener Schäden', 'Fotos DC-ÜSS', 'Fotos Erdung', 'Fotos Gesamtbild der Elektro-Anlage', 'Fotos Kabelführung',
            'Fotos Notstrom', 'Fotos Optimiererplan / Stringplan', 'Fotos - Sonstige', 'Fotos Speicher', 'Fotos Unterkonstruktion', 'Fotos Wallbox',
            'Fotos Wechselrichter', 'Fotos Zählerschrank')
            AND ( Opportunity__c =: cs.Opportunity__c OR QA_Review__c =:cs.Project_QA_Review__c 
            OR Service_Appointment__c =:cs.Service_Appointment__c OR Order__c=:cs.Order__c OR GO_Case__c =:caseId)  Limit 10])
            {

            Map <String, String> cloudFileDetails = NEW Map <String, String> ();
            if (obj.TVA_CFB__Bucket_Name__c != NULL && obj.TVA_CFB__Region__c != NULL) {
            cloudFileDetails.put ('ID', obj.ID);
            cloudFileDetails.put ('bucket', obj.TVA_CFB__Bucket_Name__c);
            cloudFileDetails.put ('region', obj.TVA_CFB__Region__c);
            cloudFileDetails.put ('fileName', obj.Name);
            cloudFileDetails.put ('fileType', obj.TVA_CFB__File_type__c);
            cloudFileDetails.put ('s3FileName', obj.ID+'.'+obj.TVA_CFB__File_type__c);
            cloudFileDetails.put('folder', obj.TVA_CFB__Folder__c);

            if (obj.TVA_CFB__External_File_name__c != null) {
            String fileName = obj.TVA_CFB__External_File_name__c;
            fileName = EncodingUtil.URLEncode (fileName , 'UTF-8');
            fileName = fileName.replace ('+', '%20');
            fileName = fileName.replace ('%2F', '/');
            cloudFileDetails.put ('externalFileName', fileName);
            cloudFileDetails.put ('s3FileName', fileName);
            }
            fileURlsMap.put (obj.Id, TVA_CFB.amazonS3Authentication.generateMultipleViewLinks (credentials,
            regionEndPoints,
            cloudFileDetails,
            2000, // URL expiration time in seconds.
            NEW Map <String, TVA_CFB__CloudFiles_MIME_Types__c> ()));
            
            FileCloud newFileCloud = new FileCloud();
            newFileCloud.folder =  obj.TVA_CFB__Folder__c;
            newFileCloud.Photo = fileURlsMap.get(obj.id);
            newFileCloud.PhotoName = obj.Name;
            if(obj.Opportunity__c != null){
                newFileCloud.ObjectSF = opportunityId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
            } else if(obj.QA_Review__c != null){
                newFileCloud.ObjectSF = projectQAId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
            } else if(obj.Service_Appointment__c != null){
                newFileCloud.ObjectSF = serviceAppId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
            } else if(obj.Order__c != null){
                newFileCloud.ObjectSF = orderId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
            }


            fileCloudList.add(newFileCloud);
            System.debug(newFileCloud);
            cloudFile.put(obj.id, obj);

            }
    }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }


        System.debug(fileCloudList);
        return fileCloudList;
    }

    public class FileCloud {
        @AuraEnabled public String ObjectSF{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String Folder{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String Photo{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String PhotoName{get;set;}
       
    
    }
```

And this is the LWC

```
<template>
    
  
    <h6>Cloud Files</h6>

    <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open={multiple}>
        <template if:true={photos}>
            <template for:each={photos} for:item="photo">
                <lightning-accordion-section name={photo.TVA_CFB__Folder__c} label={photo.TVA_CFB__Folder__c} key={photo.Id}>
                    <h2>photo.Name</h2>
                    <h2>{photo.TVA_CFB__View_File__c}</h2>
                    <!-- <template for:each={acc.Contacts} for:item="con">
                        <lightning-accordion-section name={con.Name} label={con.Name} key={con.Id}>
                            {con.Name}
                        </lightning-accordion-section>
                    </template> -->

                </lightning-accordion-section>
            </template>
        </template>
    </lightning-accordion>

</template>
```

JS

```
import {LightningElement,api,wire,track} from 'lwc';
import getPhoto from '@salesforce/apex/GetAccountContactData.getPhoto';


export default class AccordionEx extends LightningElement {
@api recordId;
@track multiple = true;
@track photos ;



@wire(getPhoto) 
wiredPhotos({
    error,
    dataPhoto
}) {
    if (dataPhoto) {

        console.log('Test');
        this.photos = dataPhoto;
        
        console.log(dataPhoto);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(dataPhoto, null, '\t'));
        
        dataPhoto.forEach(function (item, key) {
            console.log(key); 
            console.log(item); 
        });
        
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}

}
```

I was expecting to at least having the data retrieve so I could work on the structure but I couldn't' get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wiredPhotos({
    error,
    dataPhoto
}) {
```

The object passed into this method have two properties we use: `error` and `data`. If you want to keep the `dataPhoto` name, you need to alias it:

```
wiredPhotos({
    error,
    data: dataPhoto
}) {
```

The usual way we reference the parameter is with its actual name:

```
wiredPhotos({
    error,
    data
}) {
```

Comment: I manage to change that the issue I was not adding the parameter for the apex method. Also because of the data name of the other wire I have to change using this way you send me.

But Now I have another problem The image is not showing but the URL is good and I can see on the LWC the data coming from the apex controller.